# Simulate similar data to get around data sharing rules?

Tags: simulation

[Sometimes there are very nice datasets that have very strict data sharing rules](http://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/?p=5894). This makes it difficult to legally share the data so that others can build upon them. I'm interesting in finding out whether it is possible to simulate similar data that can be shared where cases are also kept similar.

Suppose I'm interested in county-level data for the US (about N=3100) and that I have a dataset that I'd like to share but can't due to some data sharing rule. I would then like to simulate some very similar data that can be shared with other researchers.

In the simple case with all normal data, one could of course just use the covariance structure and simulate a new similar dataset using e.g. `mvrnorm` from **MASS** (for R). This would however, not make it so that the cases are also similar. The new cases would be random, so that if one correlated them with some other dataset, one would not find anything.

Perhaps one could sort the dataset initially by one variable. Then after having simulated the new dataset, sort them by the same variable. This would ensure that cases are similar for that variable and also to a smaller degree for the other variables due to covariance. Perhaps one could extract a first factor of the dataset and use that for sorting to ensure maximal comparability of cases.

The question gets much more complicated if the data can be ordinal, categorical or otherwise non-normal.

Are there any methods for simulating or modifying datasets that 1) preserve their use for comparison with other data, and 2) get around data sharing rules?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy (also a lawyer)